# php foreach me crazy for concat key with value

Tags: php, foreach

here is my `$bob` array :

```
Array
(
    [n] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [m] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [l] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 64
        )

    [o] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )
      )
```

And i need to output in:

- n-1
- m-1 , m-2
- l-1 , l-4 , l-64
- o-1 , o-4

I tryed some

```
foreach ($bob as $value) {

    foreach ($value as &res)

    $value =  $bob . "-" . $res;
}
}
```

I guess its pity but i'm php newbe..
All help will welcome,
Jess

Comment: look at using `foreach ($bob as $key => $value)` and building a new array during the nested loop iterations

Comment: don't know why but it give me an Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($bob as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $res){
        echo  $key . "-" . $res ." ";
    }
}
```

The `foreach ($bob as $key => $value)` syntax gives you each key for each value. You can then loop over the $value array to get the numbers you need.

Comment: don't know why but it give me an Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @albator What happens if you do just `print_r($bob)`? Do you get the same array as your question?

Comment: @albator Are you sure? The example here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ag7-kek runs correctly.

Comment: ur exemple seems work, i need to take time to see whats going wrong,thx for your help !

Answer (score 3):

You're miss curly bracket after foreach, and missprint with &res -> $res try use foreach with $key
Try this

```
<?php

$bob = [
        'n' => [0 => 1],
        'm' => [0 => 1, 1 => 2],
        'l' => [0 => 1, 1 => 4, 2 => 64],
        'o' => [1 => 1, 1 => 4],
];

foreach ($bob as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $res) {
                echo  $key . "-" . $res . PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

This output for me

```
php test.php
n-1
m-1
m-2
l-1
l-4
l-64
o-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
foreach ($bob as $key=>$value) { 
     foreach ($value as $res){        
     echo $value =  $key . "-" . $res."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: don't know why but it give me an Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Have you tried my code ? makesure  `$bob` contains array value. I have checked, it given the expected output

Answer (score 0):

try `$res` in place of `&res` in following line:

```
foreach ($value as &res)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
it will give you exact output with , and new line
Live demo : https://eval.in/87738

$arr =array
(
    'n' => array
        (
            0 => 1
        ),

```
'm' => array
    (
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2
    ),

 'l' => array
    (
        0 => 1
    ),

'0' => array
    (
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 64,
        3 => 120,
    )
    );
   $output = '';  
    foreach($arr as $k1 =>$v1){
    $out = ' ';
     foreach($arr[$k1] as $k => $v){
      $out .= $k1.'-'.$v.',';
     }
     $output .= rtrim($out,',').'<br/>';
    }

    echo $output;
```

**Output:**

n-1
 m-1,m-2
 l-1
 0-1,0-2,0-64,0-120

Comment: @albator: can you try this?